# Why doesn't my UIScrollView Scroll when I remove UIPanguesture?

Tags: swift, uiscrollview

I have a uiscrollview that is draggable through a uipangeuseture, and at the same time I want it to be scrollable, but when the gesture is added to the view it no longer scrolls, it only becomes draggable. Even when I remove that gesture from the scrollview, it still doesn't scroll, any ideas?

how i remove gesture

```
backgroundframe.gestureRecognizers?.removeAll()
```

how i add gesture back

```
backgroundframe.addGestureRecognizer(self.guestureToAdd)
```

when I add the gesture back, the dragging works fine still, however when I remove it my scrollview stops being able to scroll and I can't figure out why

Answer (score 2):

`UIScrollView` uses gesture recognizers to detect the gestures that make it scroll and zoom. If you check the docs, you'll see that it has [`panGestureRecognizer`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiscrollview/1619425-pangesturerecognizer) and [`pinchGestureRecognizer`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiscrollview/1619381-pinchgesturerecognizer) properties you can use to access some of its recognizers directly, but they also have to be in its `gestureRecognizers` array to actually work. And (through iOS 10.3 at least) it has at least one more recognizer in its `gestureRecognizers` array that is not exposed through a dedicated property.

When you call `backgroundframe.gestureRecognizers?.removeAll()`, you're removing those recognizers. You need to remove **only** your own recognizer:

```
backgroundframe.removeGestureRecognizer(self.guestureToAdd)
```

[WWDC 2012 Session 223, “Enhancing User Experience with Scroll Views”],(https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2012/223/) discusses `UIScrollView`'s use of gesture recognizers.

Comment: wow thank you! I didn't think that scrolling would've counted as a gesture, thought it was just a property